# Unable to call a .dll function correclty

Tags: java, dll, jna

I am calling a shared .dll function using JNA Java. From the documentation, the function can be invoked to receive parameters using Visual C++ as below;

```
PMSifEncodeKcdLcl(PCHAR ff, PCHAR Dta, BOOL Dbg, PCHAR szOpId, PCHAR szOpFirst, PCHAR szOpLast);
```

From the doc:

- **ff**  - A single ASCII character.
- **Dta** - Points to a null-terminated string.
- **Dbg** - a boolean flag
- **szOpId** - points to a null-terminated string
- **szOpFirst** - points to a null-terminated string
- **szOpLast** - points to a null-terminated string

The string is built from a number of Data Fields. The format for each Data Field within the string is as follows:

- **RS FI data**
- **RS** = Record Separator.

  Indicates the start of the Data Field. A single ASCII Record Separator [RS] character (hex 1E)
- **FI** = Field Identifier - Indicates the type of data in the field. A single ASCII character.
- **data** = the actual data. A number of ASCII characters, dependent on the Field Identifier. Sometimes the data is variable in length.  The Record Separator of the following field indicates the end of a Data Field (or for the last field, the NULL character at the end of the  string).

An Answer Code is returned in field **ff**. Answer Data (if any) is returned in field **Dta**

I have cross checked the JNA documentation to confirm field mappings but still no success. After trying for days. I came up with the code below;

My Java Code:

```
/* JNA interface class
 */
public class JNALocksInterface {

        public interface LockLibrary extends StdCallLibrary {

            LockLibrary INSTANCE = (LockLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("path_to_dll", LockLibrary.class);

            public void PMSifEncodeKcdLcl(byte[] ff, byte[] dta, boolean debug, String szOpid, String szOpFirst, String szOpLast);

        }

    }


/*My Calling Class Code*/
 JNALocksInterface.LockLibrary INSTANCE = JNALocksInterface.LockLibrary.INSTANCE;
        String dta = "*R101*L101*TSingle Room*NMatu*FZachary*URegular Guest*D201805021347*O201805030111";
        String ff = "A";
        byte[] dataBytes = new byte[dta.length() + 1];
        System.arraycopy(dta.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, dataBytes, 0, dta.length());
        dataBytes[dta.length()] = 0;

        byte[] dtaByteArray = new byte[dta.length() + 1];

        byte[] ffByteArray = ff.getBytes("UTF-8");



        for (int i = 0; i < dataBytes.length; i++) {

            String s1 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(dataBytes[i] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
         //   System.out.println(s1);

           if((char)dataBytes[i] == '*')
           {
               dtaByteArray[i] = 30;
           }
           else{
                int val = Integer.parseInt(s1, 2);
               byte b = (byte) val;
               dtaByteArray[i] = b;
           }


        }
        byte[] commandCodeFinal = new byte[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < ffByteArray.length; i++) {
            String s2 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(ffByteArray[i] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
            System.out.println(s2);

            int val = Integer.parseInt(s2, 2);
            byte b = (byte) val;
            commandCodeFinal[i] = b;
        }



        String userNameBytes = "test";
        String userFirstNameBytes = "test";
        String userLastNameBytes = "test";

        INSTANCE.PMSifEncodeKcdLcl(commandCodeFinal, dtaByteArray, false, userNameBytes, userFirstNameBytes, userLastNameBytes);
```

I am getting a wrong response on field ff and dta as shown below.

```
FF Response >>  :

DTA Response >>  0101IR101L101TSingle RoomNMatuFZacharyURegular GuestD201805021347O2018050
```

I am replacing "*" with the ascii record separator.

Can someone show me how to correctly call the function using JNA? I've searched all over but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

Solved IT. Used Unicode Field separator and used JNA Memory object and it Worked!

Was also using WIndows 10 64 bit. Changed to Windows 7 32 bit and it worked!!

Replaced the code with below snippet;

```
String fieldSeparator = "\u001e"
      String dataTest = fieldSeparator+"R101"+fieldSeparator+"TSingle Room"+fieldSeparator+"FShujaa"+fieldSeparator+"NMatoke"
                    + fieldSeparator+"URegular Guest"+fieldSeparator+"D201805040842"+fieldSeparator+"O201805051245";

          String  dataTestPadded = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.rightPad(dataTest,30,'0');  

          System.out.println("Padded string >> " + dataTestPadded);

            String data = dataTest;
                    //getPayloadToSend(payLoadSample) + (char)00;


            String commandCode = "A";


            Memory commandCodeMemory = new Memory(commandCode.length()+1);
            commandCodeMemory.setString(0, commandCode);

            Memory dataMemory = new Memory(data.length()+1);
            dataMemory.setString(0, data);
            //dataMemory.setString(1, "0");


            System.out.println("Registerring >> " + INSTANCE.PMSifRegister("42860149", "BatchClient")) ;

            INSTANCE.PMSifEncodeKcdLcl(commandCodeMemory, dataMemory, false, "ZKMATU", "zACHARY", "tESTING");




            System.out.println("FF Response >>  " + commandCodeMemory.getString(0));
             System.out.println("DTA Response >>  " + dataMemory.getString(0));

         INSTANCE.PMSifUnregister();
```